# How to build the most compatible binary with Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I'm using VS2019 for C and C++ under win7
I would like to build (x32bit or x64bit?) binaries which will run correctly under all later OS, including Windows Server 2019
Do I have to set WINVER/_WIN32_WINNT ? Does this concern the building env or the target env ? and if yes, with which value ?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/modifying-winver-and-win32-winnt?view=vs-2019

Comment: Unrestricted portability is going to be an issue, given that low-end machines could be 32 bit only, while dedicated servers can be 64 bit only. But I can't see a usecase for targeting both systems with the same executable.

Comment: You rarely have to be concerned about compatibility with future versions of the Windows OS.  If it runs fine on Windows 10, it will run fine in the future with Windows 11 and 12, etc... But if you want to target older operating systems like Windows 7, you might have to do a few tweaks if you are using newer APIs and services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, unlike Linux, the building environment is almost entirely irrelevant. When linking, you don't link against the libraries in the build environment, but you link against the Windows SDK.

Strictly speaking, you probably don't *need* `WINVER` and `_WIN32_WINNT`. They mainly help to hide functions from `<windows.h>`, so you don't end up calling functions that you didn't intend to call.

But there are a few rare structures where the layout changed over Windows versions, in which case you want to use the old layout. Windows 10 supports both layouts; typically by inspecting the `.cb` member of the structure. You set this field to `sizeof(type)`, and this size will depend on the `WINVER` variable.

Comment: You all talk a lot about Windows 10, excuse me I was not precise enough : the main targets are Windows Server 2xxx.

Comment: You all talk a lot about Windows 10, excuse me I was not precise enough : the main targets are Windows Server 2xxx.  
The SDK coming with VS is the 10.1.0, will running my exe be ok if the target SDK has a smaller version ?
And we can see WS2003 and WS2008 (we still have few ones) in this header, if I don't set WINVER/_WIN32_WINNT, how can i be sure my win7-generated binary will run ok on both (which are older) ? So maybe one binary for each with the good value for the both variables ?

Comment: @Minstrel: Same idea. Windows Server also checks the `.cb` field of structures that come in multiple flavors over time. You are right to worry about the support for Server 2003 in the VS2019 SDK; it's not supported since 2015. 2008R2 is probably still supported, seeing that 2008R2 goes EOL in 2020.